# How to set ICC attribute "fp-model precise" for a single function, to prevent associative optimizations?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, compiler-optimization, icc

I am implementing [Kahan summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm), in a project that supports compilation with gcc47, gcc48, clang33, icc13, and icc14.

As part of this algorithm, I would like to disable optimizations that take advantage of the associativity of addition of real numbers.  (Floating point operations are not associative.)

I would like to disable those optimizations *only in the relevant function*.  I have figured out how to do this under gcc, using the [''no-associative-math''](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) attribute.  How can I do this in icc or clang?  I have searched without luck.

```
class KahanSummation
{
  // GCC declaration
  void operator()(float observation) __attribute__((__optimize__("no-associative-math")))
  {
    // Kahan summation implementation
  }
};
```

Other GCC attributes that would imply `no-associative-math` are `no-unsafe-math-optimizations` or `no-fast-math`.

Looking at an [Intel presentation (PDF, slide 8)](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/326703/fp-control-2012-08.pdf) or another [or another (PDF, slide 11)](http://www.nccs.nasa.gov/images/FloatingPoint_consistency.pdf), I want to set "fp-model precise" in ICC, for only this function.  The compilers I care about are ICC 13 and ICC 14.

```
class KahanSummation
{
  // ICC or clang declaration
  void operator()(float observation) __attribute__((????))
  {
    // Kahan summation implementation
  }
};
```

Comment: `__attribute__` is a GCC extension. Implement those functions in a separate translation unit and compile that using the appropriate switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__attribute__` is a GCC extension. Clang also supports that syntax to maintain some GCC compatibility, but the only optimization-related attribute it seems to support is [`optnone`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#optnone-clang-optnone), which turns off all optimizations. ICC <s>has [a few optimization pragmas](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-346BAAA5-CF2D-4A26-9194-CA840BFB34E5.htm), but nothing that does what you want to do, from what I can tell.</s> [appears to support](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-0B88D6DE-D06F-4C57-A313-11291B202C39.htm) `#pragma float_control` for VC++ compatibility, although I can't find anything on exactly how that pragma is supposed to be used in ICC's documentation, so you'll have to use [VC++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45ec64h6.aspx)'s.

What you can do, though, is to define the function you want in a separate translation unit (i.e., cpp file):

```
// Your header
class KahanSummation
{
  // Declaration
  void operator()(float observation);
};
```

---

```
// Separate cpp file - implements only this function
void KahanSummation::operator()(float observation)
{
    // Kahan summation implementation
}
```

You can then compile the separate file using whatever compiler option you need to use, and link the resulting object file to the rest of your program.

Comment: Your ICC list only lists the Intel-specific ones. There's also a second list (sibling to the one linked) which has `#pragma float_control(precise,on)` for MSVC++ compatibility.