# C++ Eigen::inverse function renders totally wrong array with ffast-math option

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, eigen, eigen3, fast-math, g++10

In Ubuntu18.04, I got issue with eigen library with array inversion function, when compile with -O3 and -ffast-math option, the number in the even number of column have wrong sign for them.

The steps to re-create:

1. docker run -v $PWD:/work -it ubuntu:18.04
2. apt update
3. apt install libeigen3-dev -y
   Install gcc version 10.3.0
4. apt install software-properties-common -y
5. add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test -y && apt update
6. apt install gcc-10 gcc-10-base gcc-10-doc g++-10 -y
7. Create the file using eigen, I use file name eigen_test.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Eigen>
int main()
{
    Eigen::Matrix4d t;
    t << 1.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0,
         0.0, 1.0, -0.0, -0.0,
         0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -0.0,
         0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0;
    std::cout << "Original matrix: \n" <<t << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Inversed matrix: \n" << t.inverse() << std::endl;
}
```

8. Compile with ffast-math option:

```
$ g++-10 eigentest.cpp -O3 -ffast-math -o a.out
$ ./a.out
Original matrix: 
 1 -0  0 -0
 0  1 -0 -0
 0  0  1 -0
 0  0  0  1
Inversed matrix: 
 1 -0 -0  0
-0 -1 -0 -0
-0  0  1  0
-0 -0 -0 -1
```

9. Re-compile without ffast-math option:

```
$ g++-10 eigentest.cpp -O3 -o a.out
$ ./a.out
Original matrix: 
 1 -0  0 -0
 0  1 -0 -0
 0  0  1 -0
 0  0  0  1
Inversed matrix: 
 1  0 -0  0
-0  1  0  0
-0 -0  1 -0
 0  0 -0  1
```

The output of two results are different, the one compiled with option: -ffast-math get -1 in the (2, 2) and (4, 4) position, and they are wrong, the correct value should be 1.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: I assume, Ubuntu 18 has a very old version of Eigen which probably had some bug in the 4x4-inverse method ...

Comment: I can reproduce this with Eigen-3.4 on GCC-11 through 13 but not with clang-15 through 17. In any case, `-ffast-math` disables signed zeros (enables `-fno-signed-zeros`) so I'm not surprised code using that misbehaves. Compiling with `-fsigned-zeros` fixes the issue but also deactivates `-fassociative-math`. Possibly related bug report: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/2263

Comment: @chtz We are upgrading from Ubuntu16.04 to Ubuntu18.04 (want to take a small step on upgrading), this test works in Ubuntu 16.04 with gcc version 5.4. In ubuntu 1804, install gcc with apt install buildessential, will get gcc 7.5, and use this gcc 7.5, this test also failed in the same way. Compare to 16.04,  Ubuntu 18.04 is newer.

Comment: @Homer512 -fsigned-zeros did fix the issues, the issue gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/2263 seems to be related. But the problem I present here is probably better for people to understand, because this just shows a simple array, you can inverse it in a second. -fno-signed-zeros can fix the error, thank you. But we do worry the performance hit on that disable fassociative-math option.

Comment: It isn't uncommon for `-ffast-math` to break linear algebra that relies on IEEE-754 semantics. See also [the warning here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1BDCSVD.html). You can try separating code into different files and compile with different options, or play with [GCC's pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html). Other than that, feel free to re-open the ticket or make a new one. But there is also [this ticket](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/1686) so I don't think you can expect a fix.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38980445/ 
"As it turns out, -ffast-math gives GCC license to make transformations that effectively introduced undefined behavior into your program, causing miscompilation with arbitraryily-large fallout. See for example PR 93806 and related bugs. So really, no, it's never safe to use."